# pub-key hash for Plutus Pioneers - self-certification challenge

Tags: public-key

The entry form for the Plutus Pioneers - self-certification challenge reads as follows:

> Please provide a Cardano public key hash

I am guessing this should be associated with a wallet.
In general I prefer to use a hardware wallet.

So my question is:
How can I get a pub-key hash from a hardware controlled wallet?

Much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a great explanation of what the public key hash is:
https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/868025141668503582/1176250735986479115

Found one method of obtaining the public key hash from a wallet receiving address using mesh:
https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/868025141668503582/1178150850288431174

Found one method of obtaining the public key hash from a wallet receiving address using cardanoscan.io:
https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/868025141668503582/1176392536726720563

Much thanks to those contributors.